# simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, xml, dataset, simplexml

So, I am stumped. I know the XML is valid, as it validates everywhere I've tried it, but this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://webservices.theshootingwarehouse.com/smart/Images.asmx">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MFGNO" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Logo" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="LogoDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <MFGNO>1</MFGNO>
        <Logo>...truncated...</Logo>
        <LogoDate>2012-07-30T00:00:00+00:00</LogoDate>
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

doesn't work when called like so:

```
$data = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```

with the error:

```
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

I am about to go insane here! There seems to be no rhyme or reason to this...

-Sam

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Yvt5g works just fine. probably an invisible character somewhere in the beginning of the XML. Try `bin2hex($data);` and show the result. It should start with `3c` as can be seen here: https://3v4l.org/oL3nD

Comment: Either what @Xatenev said, or your variable doesn’t contain what you think any more at this point. (Since you are overwriting your variable that used to contain the XML string here, `$data = simplexml_load_string($data, …`, maybe you have also done that before at some point already …?)

Comment: Whenever you provide a simplified example you should make sure that your example produces the claimed error. Additionally, become best friends with `var_dump()` for your own sanity's sake.

Comment: @Xatenev I used `bin2hex` on the straight XML input and it does start with 3c, and the error came immediately again.

I use `var_dump` extensively, and in regards to overriding `$data`, I am aware. I am checking the variable before I override it, straight before it gets into the Cache, and after. They are compared for differences (none, by the way), and then I just print the XML to see if it changes. That's where I added `bin2hex`.

Comment: @user00265 What is your PHP version? Have you compared the bin2hex to the bin2hex in my 3v4l? e.g. `$string = '//bin2hex of you'; $string2 = '//bin2hex of working 3v4l'; strcmp($string,$string2);` it should be identical. note: strcmp returns 0 if they are identical.

Comment: If they appear to be identical, please run a bare-bones example in a single php file that is not related to anything else in your project just like in https://3v4l.org/Yvt5g on your machine.

Comment: @Xatenev 7.2.11 is the version, strcasecmp returned 0 for both cached and live copies. Both cannot be parsed by my script. I see that the 3v4l link you posted last just gives me an empty object, which is the same issue I am having locally,, and it is different from an error, but the file still won't parse, and it is valid XML. I must be missing something.

Comment: @Xatenev Simply adding `trim` fixed the parser error, but now even on your example the `simplexml_load_string` is returning empty.